# How to check False booleans when using get_option?

Tags: options

Whenenver you do `get_option( 'my_option' )` and that `my_option` is literally `False` itself, you cannot simply check for `if( !get_option( 'my_option' ) )`, to see if the value exists, because it'll return `False` and the check will be meaningless.

Is there no way to check whether or not the option key `my_option` exists?

Comment: A saved value for `'my_option'` wouldn't literally be false, because booleans don't get stored in the database. `update_option( 'my_option', false );` will save a value of `'0'`, not `false`. So if you want to check if a value doesn't exist at all, do a strict check for `=== false`.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I've just tried to save an option as `False` and it doesn't even save anything, not `0`...just nothing. The documentation for `update_option` specifies that the item must be serializable if it's non-scalar. Bools are scalars, so, it should handle the serialization...yet, if I save `false`, it doesn't get saved, if I save `true`, it gets converted to `1`.  When I read: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/40007 / it seems that `get/update_option` is really messed up and I should just rely on `0/1` to do my checks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a default value for when the option does not exist. This way you can check to see if the returned value is false, or if it doesn't exist at all:

```
$value = get_option( 'my_option', $default_value );
if( $value == $default_value ) {
    // Option does not exist
} elseif ( $value == false ) {
    // Option's value is equal to false
}
```

Comment: Got it. Very useful, but I think in order to avoid doing all these checks, you can re-write `get_option` itself to return a string-as-flag so you only need to check if it's that flag that returns and assume that otherwise it's the bool `false`.

Comment: Yes of course. I was just trying to be verbose to point out the details.

Comment: @DanielSmith if this answers the question you can mark it as the correct answer

Comment: It answered my initial question, but now I've discovered some subtleti... inside WP core.